# C# EmguCV: Failed to Predict - System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm working on face recognition using a web camera. The system will continuously process the data each time a face is detected. I'm using `EmguCV`, an `OpenCV` wrapper. The code is running and able to process the data. But at one time, the system is throwing out `System.AccessViolationException` exception when executing `Emgu.CV.Face.FaceRecognizer.Predict(IInputArray image)` function, and 
 it always stops there.

Here's a part of the code that causing the problem:

```cs
public void recognizeUser(Bitmap userImage, out string label, out int confidentLevel)
{
      Image<Gray, byte> imgToRecognize = new Image<Gray, byte>(userImage).Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Cubic);
      Image<Gray, byte> grayFrame = imgToRecognize.Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Cubic);                

      var lbphResult = _lbphRecognizer.Predict(imgToRecognize); // Exception occurs here.

      label = lbphResult.Label.ToString();
      confidentLevel = (int)lbphResult.Distance;
}
```

Here's the error I got:

> **System.AccessViolationException**: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Here's the stacktrace:

```
at Emgu.CV.ContribInvoke.CvFaceRecognizerPredict(IntPtr recognizer, IntPtr image, Int32& label, Double& distance)
at Emgu.CV.Face.FaceRecognizer.Predict(IInputArray image)
```

Is this a kind of bug or am I missing something? Or is it because of so many data are being proccessed at one time? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated 19/12/2017: Here's how I capture the data:**

```cs
private void PerformDetection()
{
    while (true)
    {
        DetectionResult[] detectionResult = detection.DoDetection(detectionEngineId); // Capture the face

        foreach (var detResult in detectionResult)
        {
            string label = "0";
            int confidentLevel = 0;

            lock (detResult)
            {
                if (!IsTrainRecognition)
                {
                    Bitmap imgToRecognize = (Bitmap)detResult.FaceImage.Clone();
                    _recognition.recognizeUser(imgToRecognize, out label, out confidentLevel); // Call the function above.
                    if (confidentLevel < 40)
                    {
                        IsTrainRecognition = true;
                        // Start training new face.
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Keep training until 10 image are trained and updated in YAML file.
                }

                // Saving the detection data in local database.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code where capturing is implemented. There is a possibility of a memory leak.

Comment: I read more about it and I found something about Automatic Garbage Collection in their [wiki](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Automatic_Garbage_Collection). It says that I need to call `Dispose()` function to release the object and free some memory. I'll check if this can solve the issue.

Comment: When you use using() on IDisposable objects it will automatically dispose that object when it is not needed anymore(no reference to that object anymore).