# EmguCV C#: Load Image from YAML file

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm using EmguCV to recognize face. The main flow is that first I need to load initial face model from image file, then train the data and save it into a YAML file.

Here's a part of code to train the samples of face and save to the YAML file.

```cs
private static string executeDirectoryPath = Lib.FileHelper.GetExecutableDirectory();
private const string MODELFILE_NAME= "\\objectModel.yaml";
...
foreach (var faceMdl in faceModel)
{
    Image test = ConvertByteArrayToImage(faceMdl.UserImage);
    var faceImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(new Bitmap(test));
    faceImages.Add(faceImage.Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Cubic));
    faceLabels.Add(faceMdl.Label);
}

_lbphRecognizer.Train(faceImages.ToArray(), faceLabels.ToArray());
_lbphRecognizer.Save(executeDirectoryPath + MODELFILE_NAME);
```

The `faceModel` consists of:

```cs
public class FaceObject
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public byte[] UserImage { get; set; }
}
```

The YAML format would be something like this:

```
%YAML:1.0
radius: 1
neighbors: 8
grid_x: 8
grid_y: 8
histograms:
- !!opencv-matrix
  rows: 1
  cols: 16384
  dt: f
  data: [ 2.77777780e-02, 6.94444450e-03, 0., 6.94444450e-03,
      1.38888890e-02, 0., 0., 6.94444450e-03, 0., 0., 0., 0.,
      6.94444450e-03, 0., 0., 0., 2.08333340e-02, 6.94444450e-03, 0.,
      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2.77777780e-02, 0., 0., 0., 1.38888890e-02,
      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
      6.94444450e-03, 0., 0., 0., 2.77777780e-02, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
      0., 0., 4.16666679e-02, 0., 0., 0., 1.04166664e-01, 0.,
      1.38888890e-02, 0., 2.77777780e-02, 0., 0., 0., 1.38888890e-02,
      0., 6.94444450e-03, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 6.94444450e-03, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
      0., 6.94444450e-03, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
      0., 0., 0., 0., 2.08333340e-02, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
      2.08333340e-02, 6.94444450e-03, 0., 0., 8.33333358e-02, 0.,
      1.38888890e-02, 0., 6.94444450e-03, 6.94444450e-03, 0.,
      6.94444450e-03, 0., 6.94444450e-03, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
      6.94444450e-03, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2.08333340e-02, 0., // I'm not sure what it is, probably the matrix for the images.
      ....
labels: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 49
cols: 1
dt: i
data: [ 807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821,
   807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821,
   807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821,
   807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821,
   807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 807141821,
   807141821, 807141821, 807141821, 824113004, 824113004, 807141821,
   807141821, 1214103804, 1214103804, 1214103804, 1214103804,
   1214103804, 1214103804, 1214103804, 1214103804, 1214103804,
   1214103804, 1214103804, 1214103804, 1214103804 ]  // This is the label of the images
labelsInfo:
  []
```

Is it possible to read the YAML file and store into `faceModel`, instead from the image file? There is a case where the system might end in an unexpected error (see my previous [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768256/c-sharp-emgucv-failed-to-predict-system-accessviolationexception)). The idea is, once the system is restarted, the system can use the data that is already trained instead of using the initial data, so that no need to re-train the face.

One way I can think of is to store all `faceModel` data into local database (i.e SQLite, MongoDB), but I'm just wondering if I can just get the data from YAML file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, as far as I know, each of three available recognizers in EmguCv are actually comparing yaml and the current image. You need to re-train only if you add new faces.

Comment: That's true, but there's a case if the system unexpectedly closed (refer to previous [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768256/c-sharp-emgucv-failed-to-predict-system-accessviolationexception)), I want the system to remember the faces, thus reducing duplication.

Comment: You should create the method which you call ProcessFrame as an event handler and maybe create a Timer and each time the timer ticks it will fire an event handler. You can also control the FPS there through timer interval.